# How to remove a string and adjacent text in a file with regex?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a configuration file (nginx default.conf) in which I have this kind of strings :

```
server {
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host sudomain1.somewhere.com;
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8999/;
                }
}
server {
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host sudomain2.somewhere.com;
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8755/;
                }
}
server {
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host sudomain3.somewhere.com;
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8525/;
                }
}
```

How to subtract the configuration about subdomain2 ?

```
server {
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host sudomain2.somewhere.com;
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8755/;
                }
}
```

If it is possible, using grep would be nice !
Thank you for your precious help !

Comment: If the blocks are always the same number of lines you could do `grep -B2 -A3 'sudomain2' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this gnu awk command to get a block matching `subdomain2` using custom record separator (`RS`):

```
awk -v RS='}[[:space:]]*}[[:space:]]*' '/sudomain2/{printf $0 RT}' default.conf
server {
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host sudomain2.somewhere.com;
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8755/;
                }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** To print other blocks except the `subdomain2` use:

```
awk -v RS='}[[:space:]]*}[[:space:]]*' '!/sudomain2/{printf $0 RT}' file
server {
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host sudomain1.somewhere.com;
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8999/;
                }
}
server {
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host sudomain3.somewhere.com;
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8525/;
                }
}
```

Comment: I was imagining the question asked about printing the others but not this one, but I see how that could be open for interpretation. The change is easy, anyway; skip if matched, otherwise print.

Comment: Oh thanks @tripleee, yes you're right. I got confused by subtract. It is edited now.